# Can't make nvidia work in fresh dual boot install

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I'm trying to find out how to make my nvidia work. The instalation was successfull, and after the reboot i just can access the tty.

Machine specifications:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 GPU (6GB dedicated)
CPU:
Intel® Core™ i7 Skylake - 6700HQ 2.6 GHz, 6MB Cache (3.50 GHz com Max Turbo)
MEMORY:
32GB Memória DDR4 (2133 MHZ)
HARD DISK (HDD), SSD OU SSHD:
SSHD 1 TB com 8GB SSD
SATAE M.2:
SATAe M.2 - 480GB SATA III - 6Gb/s
TELA (LCD):
15.6" FullHD (1920 x 1080p) 16:9 LED-Backlit - (Matte)
```

I have tried to make the installation of seveveral nvidia drivers versions, the latter was the 307 version, but nothing happens...

I'm using the 16.04.01 release.

Comment: *The latter was the 307 version*? For GTX1060? The only versions supporting your card are 367, 370 and 375 (currently beta). Neither are available in the official repositories up to 16.04 (I haven't tested 16.10 so I don't know if at least 367 is already available or not). You may need to add the Graphics Drivers PPA to obtain newer versions. Please edit and post at least the Ubuntu release you installed, hopefully 16.04 or 16.10 because older releases have no good support for such brand new hardware. Update your question so I can give a detailed answer.

Comment: Hei CelticWarrior, i'm using the 16.04.01 version. Maybe you can help me with the necessary commands?? Thanks.

Comment: OK. Answer coming up in a few minutes. That *should* work. However, depending on what you already did in those attempts, unpredictable results may occur.

Answer (score 0):

1. Preliminary step - Removing old drivers:

   sudo apt purge nvidia*

   sudo reboot now
2. Adding the Graphics Drivers PPA (additional software source providing newer drivers versions):

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

   sudo apt update
3. Installing the recommended driver:

   sudo apt install nvidia-370

   sudo reboot now

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. I'm deleting the repartion and starting all again. Do you know if this can damage my machine? it's new and i already reboot i dont know... 50 times?

Comment: It won't damage it. Yes, if it doesn't work then I also suggest to start over.